# How can I determine if this .NET object is an int?

Tags: .net

I'm trying to determine if the value of this `object` is an `int`.

```
var contentType = content.GetType(); // returns 'object'.
var isANumber = contentType.IsPrimitive; // returns false.
```

The debugger shows the following:

[image]

So to me, it looks like the debugger is saying: "I have an `object` but it's actually an `int` ?" (side note: is this boxing?)

This occurs in a test I have because the input parameters for the test are like this:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(AddMessageItems))]
public async Task GivenSomeObjectContent_AddMessageAsync_AddsItToTheQueue(object content)
```

where my list of items I'm passing to the test are:

- `int`
- `string`
- `new Foo(..);`

[image]

I know I can fix this up by changing the test method to accept a `T` instead:

```
public async Task GivenSomeObjectContent_AddMessageAsync_AddsItToTheQueue<T>(T content)
```

So for arguments sake, *if* I didn't take the correct `<T>` answer ... is there a way to determine that it's really an `int` and not an `object` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isInteger = (content is int);
```

Comment: Drats. I really should have asked (as the main question) : is this object a number (which was why I was using the `.IsPrimitive` check). With this answer, I would have to `content is xxx` checks for all numbers.